# Complicated split of string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a group of similarly structured strings that I'm trying to break up into separate pieces via JavaScript.

Sample string:

> Jr. Kevin Hooks, Irene Cara, Moses Gunn, Robert Hooks, Ernestine Jackson, José Feliciano. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ullamcorper sodales nulla id hendrerit.

Ideal output:

```
[
 "Jr. Kevin Hooks","Irene Cara",… 
 "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur
  ullamcorper sodales nulla id hendrerit."
]
```

My first thought was to do a split at '. ' to separate the names from the block of text towards the end, then split the group of names at ', ', but because some names are like 'Jr. Kevin Hooks' and the block of text also contains '. ' that approach fails. Using ', ' as the key also fails because the block of text contains ', '.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you choose the strings separator? Or it was previously defined?

Comment: Yes, it is complicated. And feels like cannot be solved as there is no way to distinguish between author name and description unless there is delimiter at the end of authors. IMHO

Comment: Do all samples follow the exact same format of 1. Comma separated names, 2. First phrase, 3. Second phrase? In any case, you might need to use natural language processing methods for this task.

Comment: Structure is previously defined and I cannot adjust. The format is always the same 1. Comma separated names, 2. Block of text– it may have an unknown 3 of phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can assume that:

- There is no text coming before the first name occurrence
- A point in a name only occurs at the end of a word of at most 3 letters
- If the last occurring name ends with such an abbreviation, then it still needs to be followed by a point to end the list (e.g. "Abram Lincoln, John Johnsen Jr.. Lorem ipsum dolor"), as otherwise there is no way to know whether the next word belongs to the name or not.

Then you could use this regular expression:

```
/([a-z]{1,3}\.|[^\s,.]+)(\s+([a-z]{1,3}\.|[^\s,.]+))*(?=[,.])|\..*$/ig
```

```js
var text = 'Jr. Kevin Hooks, Irene Cara, Moses Gunn, Robert Hooks, Ernestine Jackson, José Feliciano. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ullamcorper sodales nulla id hendrerit.'
var result = text.match(/([a-z]{1,3}\.|[^\s,.]+)(\s+([a-z]{1,3}\.|[^\s,.]+))*(?=[,.])|\..*$/ig);
// Optionally remove the point at the start of the last match:
if (result) result.push(result.pop().replace(/^\.\s*/, ''));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Explanation:

- `[a-z]{1,3}\.` matches one to three Latin characters, followed by a point
- `[^\s,.]+)` matches one to many characters that are not white-space, comma or point
- `( | )`: either must match: the above two patterns are combined in this way, meaning that a word in a name must be either up to three Latin letters followed by a point, or any number of non white-space, not including comma nor point.
- `(\s+([a-z]{1,3}\.|[^\s,.]+))*`: optionally (`*`) allow for more words like that: match one or more white spaces, and repeat the pattern as at the start.
- `(?=[,.])` that series of words must end with a comma or a point, which is not grabbed (look ahead only): by not grabbing the point, we know for sure that the pattern at the start cannot match anymore, and that is when the next pattern will do the job:
- `\..*$` matches a literal point and then any characters up to the end of the string (`$`)

The point preceding the final text block is also included in the last match, so you may want to remove it separately (see snippet).

Comment: Wow! That is awesome. I thought a regex might be the way to go, but they are so hard for me. Thanks for the detailed explanation! And yes, dropping the point preceding the final text is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I found one corner case that I've tried to adjust the original regex, but to no avail. In the case of "will.i.am", it splits it at the first . into "will" & "i.am" and then misses all remaining names. Any idea to address it? Thanks!

Comment: That looks like an odd name? Is that real? Do you have a real-life example of such a name? What are the rules to consider a point part of a name?

Comment: haha, yeah it's real and odd. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will.i.am But there are similar scenarios. The current solution works for "J. J. Abrams", but it also could be written "J.J. Abrams". I think it is when there isn't a space, it has troubles.

Comment: OK, I just proved myself I am getting old ;-) I'll have a look at it, and come back to you.

Comment: You could try with this regex: `/([a-z]{1,3}\.|[^\s,]+[^\s,.])(\s+([a-z]{1,3}\.|[^\s,]+[^\s,.]))*(?=[,.])|\..*$/ig`: it allows points in names at any position if not followed by a space. If followed by a space, the word must still be short (1-3) letters.